Error while upload files from laravel to digital ocean spaces
I am trying to upload files to digital ocean spaces using below config.
'spaces' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('DO_SPACES_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('DO_SPACES_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('DO_SPACES_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'),
            'endpoint' => env('DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT'),
            'url' => env('DO_SPACES_URL'),
            'throw' => true,
        ],

This is th code I have used to upload
$path = 'thumb.png';
$result = Storage::disk('spaces')->put($path, @file_get_contents(public_path('assets/images/favicon.png')));

Getting below 400 error
Unable to write file at location: thumb.png. Error executing "PutObject" on "https://{bucket-name}.blr1.digitaloceanspaces.com/thumb.png"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: PUT https://{bucket-name}.blr1.digitaloceanspaces.com/thumb.png resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: InvalidArgumenttx0000068bc0c6000 (truncated...) InvalidArgument (client): - InvalidArgumenttx0000068bc0c6000b2676c-00662b4290-1c5ffb0-blr1a1c5ffb0-blr1a-blr1-zg01

Is that value the error message mentions, one of the env variables you are putting into spaces config array there?

No, I don't think so. I have added all the config.
